# Gauss Seidel Vs Gradient Descent for nonlinear systems

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gradient-descent

Gradient descent is used to minimize an error and Gaus Siedel is used to solve a system of equation.

My question is simple:
Is there any difference in results if I try to solve the solution $x$ from nonlinear system $$0 = f(x)-b$$ where $b$ is a vector, if I'm using Gradient descent VS Gaus Seidel?

1. Should I except more accuracy with Gaus Seidel?
2. Should I except Gaus Seidel is robust against local minimums?
3. Should I except Gaus Seidel working faster than Gradient descent?
4. Should I except Gaus Seidel work for all nonlinear systems?
5. Should I except Gaus Seidel be more robust than Gradient descent?

Comment: Can you specify what are you calling Gauss-Seidel method? It is normally an iterative method for *linear* systems.

Comment: @PierreCarre Only linear systems? If that's the case, then Gradient Descent have a point there compared the Gauss-Seidel.

Comment: What experiments have you performed to compare the two methods?

Comment: @CarlChristian I haven't made any experiments. I just heard that Gauss Seidel can be used for nonlinear systems. So then makes me wonder if Gauss Seidel is better then simple gradient descent.

Comment: There is simply no substitute for your own experiments. Program both routines and select equations for which you know the exact solution.

Comment: @CarlChristian Well, I have program C code for gradient descent. It works. But I don't know if gauss siedel is better. I just heard that it could be used to solve nonlinear systems as well as linear systems.

Comment: Good, then you are halfway there. Google the exact string "nonlinear gauss seidel" and examine one of the YouTube videos. You will need an implementation of say the secant method to solve the individual scalar equations. It is likely that you will find that no method is always better than the other.

Comment: @CarlChristian Have you tried gauss siedel?

Comment: Yes. In the GROMACS library it is used to solve bond constraint equations in the SHAKE algoritm for molecular dynamics. In this context it is reliable, but so slow that high accuracy is rarely achieved.

Comment: @CarlChristian So it's very slow algorithm? That's what I'm not looking for.

Comment: @CarlChristian Tack så mycket för svar.